# Обработчик для подпапок в корне wp

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Сервер на nginx. WP стоит в корне. В папке /ua/wp-content/uploads/*.* лежит старый контент
Как при обращении site.com/ua/ получать не 403 а страницу сайта которая должна там быть
P.S. Если удалить папочку /ua/ то страница есть

Comment: Что значит "В папке /ua/wp-content/uploads/. лежит старый контент" ? Какая у тебя вообще структура каталогов? (исправляй вопрос)